# How to literally take Google Maps page and put it into website for my products?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am new to Ruby on Rails and need to know how I would get Google Maps map to show inside of my website as if a user was using Google similar to when sites use Google Search.

I want the scenario to play out like this:

Users create products and on the form is a partial which displays the Google Maps so they can look for the address, confirm it and then save it (by link or screenshot) with a specific Product. How can i make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [Google Maps Javascript API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/), plus some Javascript know how.

Comment: I am basically a newbie at anything programming, been at Ruby on Rails for 6 months now, i am just starting to look in to Javascript, it would help wonders if you could recommend one exceptional guide for understanding the basics Javascript/Jquery uses.

Comment: Check the top answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript .  Also try w3schools for the real basics, then http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#.  But most of all, just start working on stuff, making sure to cross research best practices and alternatives as you go.